# How does FLEX session management work

Tags: apache-flex

This is a pretty low level question...I'm trying to do a performance test of a JSP\Flex application and I notice in the AMF traffice that some sort of FLEX session seems to be used. All the AMF calls refer to a "DSId" which seems to be an identifier for the session.

I need to be able to work out what this DSId is by examing the HTTP traffic. Note there are no options to use any of the flex tools or libraries although I can call out to external Java or .Net libraries if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at [Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/) Media Server (written in Java), apart from server-side implementation of AMF handling, they have some client-side AMF implementation in their code base.